# How to get _id value in Meteor template

Tags: templates, meteor

Here is my template snippet.

```
{{#if is_multiple_choice _id}}
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="input-field col s11">
      <select id="ans_{{_id}}" name="answer" class="multiple_choice_answer">
        <option value="">No Answer Given for Multiple Choice</option>
      {{#each allowed_values}}
        {{#if matched value _id}}
          <option value="{{value}}" selected>{{value}}</option>
        {{else}}
          <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
      </select>
      <label>{{text}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

So I aimed to use _id in "matched" helper, but it seems the _id in matched value _id line gets nothing.

How can I get _id and use it in "matched" helper?

Please help me!!!

Comment: within the #each loop you are in a chil context, so to access parent context you need `../_id` or within the template helper you can return  `Template.instance().data._id`

Comment: HI MrE, your answer is valuable, so I want to mark your answer as acceptable, please post answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `{{#each}} {{/each}}` loop, you are in a **child** context

To access the **parent** context, you need to use the `..` notation, like this: `../_id`.

You can also use `this` within a Template.helper to get `this._id`:

```
Template.example.helper({
    "id": return this._id;
});
```

You can then use `id` anywhere in the Template.

**Note:**

1) `this._id` is equivalent to `Template.instance().data._id` within a helper.

Use `Template.instance().data` to access the template data context within an `event`, `onCreated` or `onRendered`.

2) The `..` notation can be used to access the grand-parent template as well, with `../../_id` for example.

This `..` pattern is acceptable to access parent context from a `{{#each}}` loop within the same Template for example, but it is not recommended to use with child templates (to access parent template) because your child template is not reusable without the parent template context.